# Bounds for the exponential integral

Tags: analysis, integration, inequality

In  [Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/)
(on page 229, property 5.1.20) it is stated that

$$
\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1 + \frac{2}{x} \right) < \exp(x) E_1(x) < \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) \qquad (x > 0)
$$

where

$$
E_1(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{\exp(-t)}{t} dt
$$

How does the proof go?

Comment: Here's a [published and freely available proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357130831_On_Some_Bounds_for_the_Exponential_Integral_Function). I have not checked the details and it would be nice to find a more accessible argument.